# How can I load an image from the OpenGL/Glfw clipboard?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, clipboard, glfw

I am making a program that loads images and displays them with OpenGL / Glfw. I have managed to load the images from a path but I also want to do it from the windows clipboard. **With text it works for me to read it**. But when **I copy an image from windows** explorer nothing comes up or **it tells me that the clipboard is empty.**

```
bool FeatherGUI::loadFromClipBoard() {
    std::cout << "Loading from clipboard" << std::endl;
    //Show content of clipboard with glfwGetClipboardString
    const char* clipboard = glfwGetClipboardString(this->windowContext);
    if (clipboard == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Clipboard is empty" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }else{
        std::cout << "Clipboard content: " << clipboard << std::endl;
    }
    return true;
}
```

How can I get what I want?

Comment: The data in the Windows clipboard is typed (image, text etc).  I looks like glfw only support text clipboard data.  You will need to use the native Windows clipboard API to read non-text data. [Using the Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GLFW doesn't provide that functionality at the moment.

See issue [#260, "Support for clipboard image data"](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/260).

[GLFW's Windows implementation of `glfwPlatformGetClipboardString()`](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/3.3.8/src/win32_window.c#L2285-L2322) lives in [`src/win32_window.c`](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/3.3.8/src/win32_window.c) if you feel like taking a stab at adding [`CF_BITMAP`/`CF_DIB`/`CF_DIBV5`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats) support.